# Quicker way to compare numbers without calculator

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, soft-question, numerical-methods, gre-exam

Question: Find the order of $(1/2)^{1/2}$, $(1/e)^{1/e}$, $(1/3)^{1/4}$ without using calculator.

Extra constraint: You only have about 150 seconds to do it, failing to do so will eh... make you run out of time on the exam which affects the chance of admitting into graduate school!

Back to the question, when I first saw it I tried to use $(1/2.7)^{1/3}$ to approximate $(1/e)^{1/e}$, compare the $12^{th}$ power of each number and end up in getting the wrong result.

Later(too late!) I find out $f(x)=(1/x)^{1/x}$ has minimum at $x=e$ by taking the derivative $f'(x)=f(x)(ln(x)-1)/x^2$. In addition, second derivative or some kind of feeling is required to make sure it's minimum not maximum. However I feel this approach might unnecessarily take too long.

Had you seen this question, what would have been your first instinct/approach? Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: Gut reaction is just to use $f$ for the first two and guess on the last one based on $f(3)$ and $f(4)$. Not sure how fast or reliable that is. [Note: you would expect $e$ to be a minimum, not a maximum, because $f\to\infty$ as $x\to 0$, so I wouldn't bother with that calculation.]

Comment: The first derivative test gives you that that's a local minimum at e by inspection,  every term is positive except $\ln(x)-1$ for all positive x,  so you have it's decreasing before e and increasing after e

Comment: Is the third numer $(1/3)^{1/4}$ or may be $(1/3)^{1/3}$...?

Comment: It's $(1/3)^{1/4}$ if I remember it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd first raise to the power $4$, to find $1/4 < 1/3$. Or if this is a typo, raise to the power of 6 to find $1/8 < 1/9$.

For the comparisons with $1/e$, I'd take the logarithm, and do comparisons, knowing $ln(2)$ is about $0.69$, and $ln(3)$ is more than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac14}>\left(\frac14\right)^{\frac14}=\left(\frac12\right)^{\frac12}.$$

Knowing there is a minimum at $x=e$,

$$\left(\frac1e\right)^\frac1e<\left(\frac12\right)^{\frac12}<\left(\frac13\right)^{\frac14}.$$

Hint:

Take $\log(x^x)=x\log x$, derivative $\log x+1$, second derivative $1/x>0$: it has a minimum at $1/e$.

Comment: Consider using \left( ... \right)  or \big( ... \big) if the contents is rather tall. "Big' is simpler, but 'left-right' automatically adjust the parens' height to the expression inside.